# input text box automatically when combobox changed

Tags: c#

i have three combobox and one textbox in my form application,

this is the combobox and textbox

[image: Combobox and TextBox]

the question is, how to input text box automatically when combobox changed.

example :

1 : 
when i choose combobox 1 "value" then textbox value changed to +1

when i choose combobox 1 "select radio" the texbox value changed to null so the textbox value is ""

2:

when i choose combobox 1 "value" then textbox value changed to +1

when i choose combobox 2 "value" then textbox value changed to +1 so the textbox value is "2"

Comment: The combobox should have an OnChange event or something of that nature.  You can respond to the change of the value in that event.  Generally double-clicking on the combobox in the forms designer will take you to that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind all 3 combo boxes SelectedIndexChanged event to one event handler and call a generic function to calculate the count.

Example:

```
private void cmbBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RecalcTotal();
}

private void RecalcTotal()
{
     int counter = 0;
     if(cmbBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
         counter++;
     if(cmbBox2.SelectedIndex > 0)
         counter++;
     if(cmbBox3.SelectedIndex > 0)
         counter++;

     txtBox1.Text = string.Empty;
     if(counter > 0)
         txtBox1.Text = counter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: some error in `string.empty` and `counter` because string to int

Comment: Edited the answer to fix those issues.

Comment: `cmbBox1` , `cmbBox2`, `cmbBox3` call `RecalcTotal();` ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    HoolHandlers();
    LoadValues();
}

private void HoolHandlers()
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxItemChanged;
    comboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxItemChanged;
    comboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBoxItemChanged;
}

private void LoadValues()
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("select radio...");
    comboBox1.Items.Add("value");

    comboBox2.Items.Add("select radio...");
    comboBox2.Items.Add("value");

    comboBox3.Items.Add("select radio...");
    comboBox3.Items.Add("value");
}

private void ComboBoxItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    ComboBox combo = (ComboBox) sender;
    if (combo.SelectedItem == "value")
    {
        int tbValue;
        if (textBoxContainingValue.Text != "")
        {
            tbValue = int.Parse(textBoxContainingValue.Text);
            tbValue++;
        }
        else
        {
            tbValue = 1;
        }

        textBoxContainingValue.Text = tbValue.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        textBoxContainingValue.Text = "";
    }

}
```

Note that all the logic you want is in the ComboBoxItemChanged function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is correct..is it you need to add 1 for every selected combobox?

```
private void ComboBoxItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Int32 b1 =  (cmbBox1.SelectedIndex > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    Int32 b2 =  (cmbBox2.SelectedIndex > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    Int32 b3 =  (cmbBox3.SelectedIndex > 0) ? 1 : 0;

    Int32 Total = b1 + b2 + b3;
    txtBox.Text = (Total > 0 ) ? Total.ToString() : String.Empty;
}
```